# Count how many times a word appears in a text file

Tags: python-2.7

```
def paraula(file,wordtofind):

    f = open(file,"r")
    text = f.read()
    f.close()
    count = 0
    for i in text:
        s = i.index(wordtofind)
        count = count + s
    return count
paraula (file,wordtofind)
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exception did you get? There are at least two exceptions you'll hit with the code as-is that have nothing to do with counting words in a string.

Comment: `for i in text` will return each character one by one, so all other things equal you'll only find single character words that way. Next, assuming that's resolved, `s = i.index(...)` will return the position in the string the word was found, so incrementing by `s` will skew your count considerably. Also, if the word isn't found, [you'll get a `ValueError` exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). This is actually to your advantage, because you don't really care about the index, you just want to know if it was found or not.

Comment: Finally, [do you care about overlapping matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def paraula(file,wordtofind):
    f = open(file,"r")
    text = f.read()
    f.close()
    count = 0
    index = text.find(wordtofind) # Returns the index of the first instance of the word
    while index != -1:
        count += 1
        text = text[index+len(wordtofind):] # Cut text starting from after that word
        index = text.find(wordtofind) # Search again
    return count

paraula (file,wordtofind)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Why reinvent the wheel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900059/2125392)

```
def word_count(filename, word):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().count(word)
```