# How to find a string in a text file

Tags: python, string

I need to write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then the program should print: 2

thought to use: `mystring.find('bob')` but Im not sure about this...

Comment: what did u try so far ?

Comment: clear you question first. may be this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string
Thanks

Comment: thanks, the link actually led me to the answer:                                                s = 'xbxbxbbobobxvbcvbgb'
sb = 'bob'
results = 0
sub_len = len(sb)
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+sub_len] == sb:
        results += 1
print("Number of times 'bob' occurs is: ' " + str(results))

Comment: @troy search on google and on SO before posting

Comment: Also, please don't post code on the comments. If you have an answer, it can go below *as an answer*

Answer (score 0):

`str.find` will return the position at which the string is found.  For example:

```
"abc".find ("b")  # Returns 1, because it is found at index 1 in the string array.
```

The find the number of occurrences in the string use:

```
"ababac".count ("ba")  # Returns 2, because there are 2 "ba" in the string.
```

Read more on `str.count` here: [count string occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer I managed to get to. probably one of many:

`s = 'xbxbxbbobobxvbcvbgb'
    sb = 'bob' 
    results = 0 
    sub_len = len(sb) 
    for i in range(len(s)): 
      if s[i:i+sub_len] == sb: 
      results += 1 
    print("Number of times 'bob' occurs is: ' " + str(results))`