# Calculating the occurrence of specific words in a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with some lines as follows

3NHE,A,503,LYS,NZ,10.246915660855539,positive,A,444,PRO,CB
3NHE,A,440,ASP,OD1,11.166332392875592,positive,A,439,TRP,CB
3NHE,B,42,ARG,NH1,8.076673650559258,positive,B,44,ILE,CD1
3NHE,B,6,LYS,NZ,6.366139095873315,positive,A,489,PHE,CD2
3NHE,A,503,LYS,NZ,10.246915660855539,positive,A,444,PRO,CG
3NHE,A,503,LYS,NZ,10.246915660855539,positive,B,70,VAL,CB
3NHE,B,6,LYS,NZ,6.366139095873315,positive,A,444,PRO,CG
3NHE,B,76,GLY,OXT,4.547711997741236,positive,A,277,PHE,CB

I want to calculate the number of times the words ‘ASP and ‘LYS’ has occured in the whole file 
Can somebody please tell me how to do this?
Example answer is

ASP: 5
LYS: 4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already loaded the data, you can see here how to count the number of occurrences of a substring inside a string:

[Count number of occurrences of a given substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)