# How to count the occurence of letter combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to count how often a sequence multiple characters occurs in a string. For example, I want to see how many times `ad` appears in `badhadmad`. I thought about using a `for` loop but I don't know how to iterate more than one character. How can I accomplish ths?

Comment: How about simple `"badhadmad".count('ad')` :)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of occurrences of a given substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: @Chris But `"ababa".count('aba') == 1` :D?

Comment: @TrebledJ True! `str.count` won't work in such cases. In that case, iteration is indeed one way: `sum(1 for i in range(len("ababa")) if "aba" == s[i:i+len("aba")])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to count the number of occurrences of a sub-string in python.

```
s = "badhadmad"

print(s.count("ad"))
```

Using loop:

```
s = "badhadadmad"
l = len(s)
pattern = "ad"
n = len(pattern)
count = 0
for i in range(l - n):
  if s[i] == pattern[0]:
    if s[i:i+n] == pattern:
      count += 1
print("Ans",count)
```

.count() gives only non-overlapping solution, for overlapping sub-strings:

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('(?=aba)', 'ababa')))
```

Comment: Also, why the double check on the first character?

Comment: I'd like to know if it is a major computational redundancy?

Comment: probably a small one, but in Python readability counts :) Also count on Python to do the check efficiently. I'm sure that by doing `s[i:i+n] == pattern` if the first character doesn't match, no extra computation will be carried out

Comment: True that but I think readability is a subjective thing. Some find it redundant what other may find readable and vice versa.

Comment: Well with that I can't argue obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use **`count`** method over a string in python

```
x = "badhadmad"
x.count("ad")
# 3
```

Go through https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count for more usage of **count** method

Answer (score 0):

Generate character level n grams for your string str,

```
[str[i:i+n] for i in range(len(str)-n+1)]
```

and then use count if needed. You can loop over range of values of n you want to consider.