# Pythonic way to get the count of a list of chars from a sentence

Tags: python, string, list

New to Python.

Say I wanted to get the total number of '.' or '!' in a body of text, what is the 'pythonic' way of doing so? I'd think there would be something like: `text.count(LIST)`

I realize the below would work, but wondering what the python people think.

```
for char in list(text):
    if char in LIST:
        sum += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of occurrences of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string) Then you could just add the numbers of occurrences of `.` and `!` up.

Comment: `total = text.count('.') + text.count('!')`
works but seems a bit inelegant to me

Comment: you want something like `counts = collections.Counter(text); total = sum(counts[c] for c in LIST)`