# Find how many times string appears in another python

Tags: python, string, methods

Is there a method in python in order to check how many times a string appears in another?
For example

```
a="1ab1"
new_string="1ab1ab1ab1"
```

I should get 3 but I got 2 with str.count()

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of occurrences of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: `"aba3abaa".count("aba")`?

Comment: Use string.count(pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will count the number of substrings with overlap in a string:

```
def getSubstringCount(s1, s2):
    pos = 0
    count = 0
    while pos < len(s1):
        pos = s1.find(s2, pos)
        if pos == -1:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            pos += 1
    return count

a="1ab1"
new_string="1ab1ab1ab1"
cnt = new_string.count(a)
print(cnt)
```

Output: `3`

Comment: and if is it something like that
`string="1ab1ab1ab1"`
and `a="1ab1"`
I should get 3 but I got 2