# Find occurrence of a string in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, data-structures

Details:

- There are two strings `x` and `y`.
- Count the number of `occurrence of y in x` as follows:

  - Length of y is 3.
  - Increment the "count" value when `y == x[i] x[i+2] x[i+4]`

Example:

```
x = "aabbcc"
y = "abc" 
output: 2
```

My Code:

```
def solution(x, y):
    i, count = 0, 0
    j = i + 2
    k = i + 4
    
    while i+4 < len(x):
        cur = x[i]
        while i < len(x) and i != j:
            i += 1
        while i < len(x) and i != k:
            i += 1
        count += 1
        
    return count
    
solution(x, y)
```

I am getting `count = 1`. It should give `count = 2`

Comment: trying adding a `print(i)` statement above the line that's giving you the error, then try to establish how these values of `i` are being generated

Comment: I'm not sure why your question was downvoted, it appears to meet basic criteria. However, the problem is fairly easy to spot. Your error message will have included a line number (it's a good idea to share the entire stack trace in the question). And the line it fails on is the second `res.append(x[i])` - this happens because you increase `i` under certain conditions, but don't check that it no longer fits within the string. (also, it appears that in the problem description, it should read `y == x[i] x[i+2] x[i+4]` for any `i`)

Comment: @Grismar I have modified my question. can you please take a look now?

Comment: @Grismar I downvoted the question because it does not show an attempt to analyze the problem or to understand why/where the code goes wrong; and because a straightforward solution is available by combining two elementary techniques that are covered in very popular canonical duplicates. I don't want to close the question as a duplicate because it *can* be approached other ways; but right now, it isn't even clear whether to approach this as a technique question or a debugging question. I voted to close as "needs more focus" on these grounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of logic errors in your code.

The problem happens here:

```
        while i < len(x) and i != j:
            i += 1
        res.append(x[i])
```

You keep increasing `i` until it is either `len(x)` or greater, or until it is the same as `j`. But since you set `j` to be `2` at the start (and never update it), it will simply end up setting `i` to `len(x)`. And `x[i]` will thus fail, since `x[len(x)]` tries to index an element just outside `x`.

However, there's a few more remarks to make:

- you collect what you find in `res`, but really only want a number (e.g. `2`) as a result
- you define `count` but don't use it
- you track the coordinates in the string in three separate variables (`i`, `j`, `k`) and have a lot of logic to increment the first, but really all you need is to step through the string one position at a time, and look at the offsets directly

Given all that and the problem description, you were probably going for something like this:

```
x = "aabbcc"
y = "abc"


def solution(x, y):
    i, count = 0, 0

    while i + 4 < len(x):
        if (x[i], x[i+2], x[i+4]) == (y[0], y[1], y[2]):
            count += 1
        i += 1

    return count


print(solution(x, y))
```

However, Python has some cleverness that would make it even simpler (or at least shorter):

```
def solution(x, y):
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(x)-4):
        if x[i:i+5:2] == y:  # slicing with a stride of two, instead of direct indexing
            count += 1

    return count
```

Or even:

```
def solution(x, y):
    return len([x for i in range(len(x)-4) if x[i:i+5:2] == y])
```

But that's favouring brevity over readability a bit too much, I feel.

Comment: The last one building a list repeating is weird. Mine was `sum(x[i:i+5:2] == y for i in range(len(x)))` (yes I'm too lazy to think about how much to subtract exactly).

Comment: @KellyBundy user Nick contributed that solution already - I went for this, since it takes OP's idea of collecting the results in a list and then somehow getting to the answer from that. I wouldn't write it like that for any real situation though. Nick's solution (and yours, adding the `- 4`) is clever, if brevity is key.

Comment: Ah yes, hadn't scrolled down yet. Ok, I see that and raise you a `[*zip(x,x[2:],x[4:])].count((*y,))`.

Comment: @KellyBundy that one doesn't even need a code obfuscator! :)

Answer (score 1):

A generator expression solution, taking advantage of `True/False == 1/0` in a numeric context:

```py
def solution(x, y):
    return sum(y == x[i:i+5:2] for i in range(len(x)-4))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Increment the "count" value when y == x[i] x[i+2] x[i+4]

This is the same as simply creating the string consisting of `x[0], x[2], x[4]...` (every even-numbered character) and the string consisting of `x[1], x[3], x[5]...` (every odd-numbered character); counting the occurrences of `y` in each; and adding those two results together.

Creating the strings is trivial, and a [common duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/). Counting occurrences of a substring is [also well-trodden ground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905). Putting these tools together:

```
def spread_substrings(needle, haystack):
    even_haystack = haystack[::2]
    odd_haystack = haystack[1::2]
    return even_haystack.count(needle) + odd_haystack.count(needle)
```

Comment: Yes. There is nothing in OP's specification to suggest that the answer shouldn't be `2`. The problem OP reports is due to the interlacing, not due to overlooking an overlapping match. If OP **wants** overlapping matches, *there are other answers at the linked duplicate explaining how to deal with that*.  Frankly, I am starting to get the impression you have a personal vendetta against me, and I don't appreciate your pattern of nit-picking my answers and/or comments with pithy or sarcastic remarks.

Comment: I'd say their specification *"Increment the "count" value when y == x[i] x[i+2] x[i+4]"* rather clearly allows overlapping. No "personal vendetta", I don't even remember interacting with you before.

Comment: That is interlacing, not overlapping. Overlapping is detecting a match on `x[i+2] x[i+4] x[i+6]` *in addition to* that one. Interlacing is detecting a match on `x[i+1] x[i+3] x[i+5]` in addition - which my code does, because it works by explicitly deinterlacing first.

Comment: No, the one you're missing is for i=2, because it *overlaps* the one for i=0.

Comment: That's... what I said.

Comment: Wasn't in your comment initially. Now your comment says it's not overlapping and then right away explains that it's overlapping. I think you misunderstood my point, I didn't mean the step=2 part of their specification, I meant the incrementing the count for every i where a certain condition holds. Phrased as that is, I really think there's no reason to not count the match for i=2. It suggests doing what the other answers did (loop over the possible i-values and check/count).