# How to find multiple occurrences of a substring in a Python string using dictionary values?

Tags: python

So i m creating a program that will find a motiff and the position of the motiff in a sequence inside a fasta file. A motiff is like a specific string introduced by the user. So for example in this sequence ACCTGCTTCCGTTCGAGTTCAGTT and the motiff is GTT it needs to report that there is two occurrences and their positions.

I tried using the following code since my species name and sequence are stored inside a dictionary

```
def MotiffFinder(Dicionario, Motiff):
  for key, value in Dicionario.items():
    for Motiff in value:
       print(value.index(Motiff))
```

i also tried
`find()`
but it doesnt seem to work since it reports positions where the motiff is not in.
Help

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string

Comment: `for Motiff in value:` will run the loop once for each CHARACTER in the value.  What you need a loop with `value.find`.  Remember that you can specify to `find` where to start looking.  So, look for the  next sequence starting just after the previous one.