# Bob Counter in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I was attempting to count the number of occurances of 'bob' in the phrase 'bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj.' To do this, I wrote the code below:

```
  b=0
  string='bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj'
  string = string.lower()

  for i in string:
     if(([i:i+3]=="bob") or ([i:i+3]=="BOB")'):
        b=b+1

  print ("Number of times bob occurs is:%s" %b)
```

However, when I run it, it outputs 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: There are quite a few simple errors in this program. I'd really encourage you to try resolving them for yourself -- look at examples of Python code, look at how they're solving problems, and compare them to what you're doing -- before asking here.

Comment: `bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj` is not a string while `"bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj"` is. You may want to learn something about string slicing, search on google for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic indexing recurrences of a substring within a string (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987702/basic-indexing-recurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-python)

Comment: `i` is only 1 character at a time, so your `if` will always fail ( 'b' is never equal to 'BOB' ). Also, there's and indentation error on your 6(?)the line, after the `if` statement.

Comment: If you don't need to count overlapping occurrences, you could do `print 'bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj'.count("bob") + 'bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj'.count("BOB")` (though this is the ugly way). You could also use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's see if we can help you out.

Your code is

```
s='bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj'

 for i in s:

     if(i=='BOB' or i=='bob'):
        b=b+1
```

It is important to think about this- a string like "s" is a list of characters.  When you do for i in s, you are looping through each individual character.

on the first iteration, i == 'b', on the second one it equals 'o' and so on.

What you want is something that checks sections of code.  a way of doing that would be

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+4] == "bob":
```

The reason this works is that range returns a list of numbers in order, so it will go 0, 1, 2, 3...  the [i:i+4] part cuts out a section of the string based on the how far into the string it is.  For your string s[0:2] would be "bob"  (it starts with 0).

I left several problems... for example, if you let it run to the end you'll have a problem (if s is 10 characters long and you try to do s[9:12] you will get an error) ... but that should help you get going

Comment: Not sure exactly what you typed in but it worked in my editor.  As a note, I wasn't paying a ton of attention, but as "bob" is three letters long, it should be [i:i+3]...

Comment: @Zak Shaky The code in this answer is syntactically OK. Update your question with code that you've written, so we'll see where's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'bobbbobobboobobookobobbobbboj'
>>> term = 'bob'
sum(1 for i, j in enumerate(s) if s[i:i+len(term)] == term)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Bob Counter Program Answer In Python**

```
s = ('bobobobobobob') #Declare the variable 's' and assign it to a string with 6 bobs in it.
count = 0 #Declare the variable 'count' and set it equal to 0.

for i in range(len(s)): # for the number i in the length of 's' (12 in our example)
    if s[i:i+3] == "bob": # Example: if s[0:3] == 'bob' is true
        count += 1 # Increase count by 1 to keep track of how many times 'bob' occurs.
  # else :
      # 'count' is not incremented because the string does not equal 'bob'.
      # It most likely says 'obs' in our example instead of 'bob'.

    # Next number. On the second loop, i increments from 0 to 1 and it loops through again.

print ('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(count)) # Output: 'Number of times bob occurs is: 6'
```

If you need further explanation on this, I would recommend that you put this into a python IDE such as http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and step through the program.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Yes I did this a long time ago. I will update the documentation on this when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the Pythonic way, then you'll want to read up on the [string find function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm).

If you want to learn how make a string find function, then you'll want to read up on  [string searching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation based on [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6988110/227646) to a linked question.

```
def MIT(full_string, substring):
    results = []
    sub_len = len(substring)
    for i in range(len(full_string)):
    # range returns a list of values from 0 to (len(full_string) - 1)
        if full_string[i:i+sub_len] == substring:
        # this is slice notation;
        # it means take characters i up to (but not including) i
        # + the length of th substring
            results.append(i)
    return results

full_string = "bobBOBBobBoj"
lower_substring = "bob"
upper_substring = "BOB"
lower_occurrence_array = MIT(full_string, lower_substring)
upper_occurrence_array = MIT(full_string, upper_substring)
number_of_lower_occurrences = len(lower_occurrence_array)
number_of_upper_occurrences = len(upper_occurrence_array)
number_of_occurrences = number_of_lower_occurrences + number_of_upper_occurrences

print ("Number of times bob occurs is: %s" %number_of_occurrences)
```

The result is

> Number of times bob occurs is: 2

The main gist is already there with [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626062/227646) but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
start=0
count=0 
while start<=len(s):
    n=s.find('b',start,len(s))
    prnt=(s[start:start+3])
    if prnt =='bob':
       start=n+2 
       count+=1
    else:
        start+=1        
print count
```

Comment: sexy anwer, just do some indenting if code not running properly but has been accepted by mit's online judge

Answer (score 0):

```
def bobcount(x):
    bobcounter = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if (x[i:i+3]=="bob") or (x[i:i+3]=="BOB"):
            bobcounter = bobcounter + 1
    return bobcounter
```

This is an extension of Paul's answer. The result of the code is:

```
bobcount("bobobobBOBBOB")
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess i am a little bit late, but you can try this:

```
from re import findall

    def bobcount(word):
        return len(findall(r'(bob)', word.lower()))
```