# In Python why do some people include len(s)-2 in some cases for finding a word in a string?

Tags: python, string

Consider:

```
s = input("Enter a string")
n=0
for count in range(len(s)):
  if s[count:count+3] == "bob":
   n = n+1
print("Number of times bob occurs is: " ,n)
```

Why do some people use `range(len(s)-2)` in their code instead of `range(len(s))` although both give the right output?

I just don't understand the `len(s)-2` part.

Comment: refine your question. It's unclear.

Comment: Why you don't use `count` ?  Try like this `s.count('bob')`

Comment: It's just a micro optimization. Since you are looking for a word of length 3 you can stop when you know there are no more 3 letter words available to process

Comment: Could you give an example of coffee where len(s)-2 is used?

Comment: What sisanared said. FWIW, there are better ways to count the number of times that a substring occurs in a string. If you are looking for non-overlapping matches you can use the `str.count` method, otherwise you can use `str.find` in a loop. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987702/basic-indexing-recurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-python

Comment: @sisanared thank your for the explanation.

Comment: BTW, `len(re.findall('(?=bob)', s))` does the exact same thing ;)

Comment: @sisanared, convert it to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The last two `count` values in the for loop, `count = len(s)-2` and `len(s)-1` lead to substrings with only 2 or 1 characters, which cannot be equal to a 3 character string.

Answer (score 0):

"bob" has three characters. So if we want to search "bob" from a given word, you only need to check till the [-3] letter...

That's why people search till len(s)-2.